# Android ndk jni problem with GetMethodID GetStaticMethodID

Tags: android, java-native-interface

i am looking for help on my one of project.
i am using latest android ndk 21d.
i am having project for android native jni.
i have so far reach to this.

`cl = env->FindClass("com/android/internal/x/x");`

this is my problem is always return NULL.

`MethodID = env->GetMethodID(cl, "xyzfunction", "(com/android/internal/x/x;[B,[B,I)I");`

I have try both GetStaticMethodID and GetMethodID return same.
Is there any way to use android internal api in JNI ?
same class GetStaticFieldID work fine. but method not able to get. i checked method is declared as public.
and able to call via binder method.

Any help recommended. if need offer for help please reply.

i have also tested

`MethodID = env->GetMethodID(cl, "xyzfunction", "([B,[B,I)I");` result is same.

Comment: How did you generate that method signature? The commas look incorrect.

Comment: Please use `javap -s` to generate internal signatures, people never get it right by themselves. You also probably should not be poking at internal Android classes.

Comment: Hello thank you guys for answers. i have reverse method to get function sign using jdx use byte[],byte[],int and return int .. i double checked same method work with binder its have different issue due to second arg is byte array which can't be send via binder.

Comment: You both are correct my my mistake is "([B,[B,I)I" now "([B[BI)I" working. thank you guys.